# Pasar una variable de un método a otro en la misma clase

Tags: java

```
package biblioteca;

public class libros 
{
    String isbn="1512", titulo, autor, annio;
    int num_ejem=15, prestado;
    public libros(String titulo, String autor, String annio, int prestado)
    {
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.annio = annio;
        this.prestado = prestado;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        System.out.println("\nInfo libro");
        System.out.println("Título: "+titulo);
        System.out.println("Autor: "+autor);
        System.out.println("Año: "+annio);
        System.out.println("ISBN: "+isbn);
        System.out.println("Ejemplares: "+num_ejem);
        System.out.println("Libros prestados: "+prestado);
        return "";
    }

    //prestar
    public void prestar(int p)
    {
        num_ejem = num_ejem-p;
        System.out.println("Quedan "+num_ejem+" libros de "+titulo); 
    }

    public void devolver(int d)
    {
        num_ejem= this.num_ejem+d;
        System.out.println("Quedan "+num_ejem+" libros de "+titulo);
    }
}
```

En el método prestar estoy guardando en la variable num_ejem la cantidad de libros que quedan. En el método prestar lo estoy realizando con el this.num_ejem y guardando la cantidad de libros que se devolvieron.

En ésta clase está todo bien. Yo tengo otra clase llamada revistas en la cuál es exactamente lo mismo. Lo que pasa en esa clase es que en el método devolver this.num_ejem tiene el valor de cero, y no sé el por qué.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes definir la variable `pres` a nivel de clase, de esta forma al cambiar su valor en el método `prestar()` puedes usar el valor de `pres` posteriormente dentro del método `devolver()` :

```
private int int pres;

//prestar
public void prestar(int p)
{    
    pres = num_ejem-p;
    System.out.println("\nQuedan "+pres+" libros de "+titulo); 
}

public void devolver(int d)
{
    int pr = pres;
    System.out.println("pres:"+pr);
    int dev;
    dev = pr+d;
    System.out.println("\nQuedan "+dev+" libros de "+titulo);
}
```

Comment: Ya lo había hecho, pero el valor de pres es cero. Es el problema que tengo. :((

Comment: Si el valor no se ha modificado, por ejemplo no se ha llamado el metodo prestar() entonces el valor siempre serìa 0, al declarar una variable int su variable inicial es 0 . Si deseas agrega todo tu còdigo para una explicaciòn mas amplia @Sercroft1

Comment: Ya puse todo el código

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones.

1. La que te dicen en el otro comentario, poner la variable pres como global. Cambiala a publico e inicializala

--  public int pres=0;

2. La otra opción es que el metodo prestar llame al devolver enviandole la variable como parametro. De esta forma devolver se ejecutará al finalizar el prestar.

```
   public void prestar(int p)
{
    int pres;
    pres = num_ejem-p;
    System.out.println("\nQuedan "+pres+" libros de "+titulo); 
    devolver(int p, int pres);
}

public void devolver(int d, int pres)
{
    int pr = pres;
    System.out.println("pres:"+pr);
    int dev;
    dev = pr+d;
    System.out.println("\nQuedan "+dev+" libros de "+titulo);
}
```